# Facebook PHP SDK how to get user email from Facebook JavaScript SDK 2014

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I am using both Facebook PHP(4.0) and JS(2.0) SDK together.
I can grab the user profile data with PHP but not the user's email.
The user's email is available with the Javascript SDK, but I need it in PHP.

I was using:

```
$user_profile = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
```

This works but the class GraphUser does not have a function to grab the user's email in 4.0.

Any ideas how I can grab user's email with Facebook PHP SDK version 4.0 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`GraphUser` inherits from `GraphObject` so you should be able to use the generic method to grab a field:

```
$user_profile->getProperty("email");
```

Comment: this only works when
`$helper = new \Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('your Url');
$helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));`
is called when getting the LoginURL.

Answer (score 15):

```
// Facebook SDK v5 for PHP
// https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_access_token_from_javascript/5.0.0

session_start();

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]);

$helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken((string) $accessToken);

$response = $fb->get('/me?locale=en_US&fields=name,email');
$userNode = $response->getGraphUser();

var_dump(
    $userNode->getField('email'), $userNode['email']
);
```

Answer (score 10):

Change login url to

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
   'scope' => 'email'
 ));
```

you can also add additional permissions like

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
   'scope' => 'email, user_activities '
 ));
```

Request permissions before you get login url.

check permissions with facebook login [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#user_friends_perms)

So you can get user email

```
 $user_profile['email'];
```

and username by

```
$user_profile['username'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Change FacebookRequest() Parameter as below.
change getLoginUrl() parameter as below

```
   $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?locale=en_US&fields=name,email' );
 $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl( array(
    'scope' => 'email'
  ));
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer by providing more info? Why should OP use this code?

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. But I didn't call FacebookRequest before getLoginUrl but in combination with getGraphUser()